# Sonarqube and code testing

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I want to run `sonarqube` testing on my `sonarqube` server and want to see test result (test report) from my client machine without touching server.

How can I do that in case of multiple developers will push their code to test on sonar server and need to see test result from their local machine?

Answer (score 3):

There is the http://www.sonarlint.org/ plugin available for eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA and Visual Studio. The plugins for first two IDEs support Java, JavaScript and PHP, the plugin for Visual Studio supports .NET code.

All three offer the **Connected Mode** which can "establish a connection to a SonarQube server (4.5.4+) and bind your [...] project to a SonarQube project."

This might help you depending on your development environment.